# django/python view testing(data from ModelForm)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have a django view which adds the data from request to database(i've done that with using ModelForms). I have this ModelForms class:

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('name', 'price', 'category',)
```

and I when the data is entered in the form I pass data in view which does this:

```
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    name_add = request.POST.get("name")
    form = AddForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST datas
    not_add = 0
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        for n in Product.objects.filter(dashboard = curr_dashboard):
            if n.name == name_add:
                not_add = 1
        if not_add != 1:
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.dashboard = curr_dashboard
            obj.save()
            curr_buylist.add_product(obj.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path()) # Redirect after POST
        else:
            forms.ValidationError("You already have this")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

else:
    form = AddForm() # An unbound form
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to test this it can't be tested because I have no request(I don't know to pass some data) here is what I have in my test:

```
    def test_model_form(self):
    product = Product(name="SomeProduct")
    product_form = AddForm({'name': 'sothingtest', 'price': 100, 'category': 1}, instance= product)
    self.assertEquals(product_form.is_valid(), True)
```

but it tests only the AddForm class

Comment: why have You moved validation out of form?

Comment: please check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: I looked in documentation, and done as there was written, validation and adding to database is in another view

Comment: > For example, if you wanted to validate that the contents of a CharField called serialnumber was unique, clean_serialnumber() would be the right place to do this. You don’t need a specific field (it’s just a CharField), but you want a formfield-specific piece of validation and, possibly, cleaning/normalizing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what You are looking for but I would do this as follows:

Move validation into Form

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name', '').strip()
        if Product.objects.filter(dashboard=curr_dashboard,
                                  name=name).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("name is not unique"))
        return name

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'price', 'category',)
```

and in the view

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = AddForm(request.POST, instance=Product(dashboard=curr_dashboard) # A form bound to  the POST datas
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        obj = form.save()
        curr_buylist.add_product(obj.id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path()) # Redirect after POST
    else:
        return {'form': form} # just return invalid form with validation errors inside
```

To test this use django TestClient (if You want test end2end behavior). If You want write unit tests You should create your own request with request dictionary populated.

You can mock form itself and test `if` logic if You want or write tests for thyis `if`.

Comment: Ill do this, but the problem is that I don't know how to pass some mock data in test to check the 'if'statement in view